# Getting low memory alert if I start MSSQL service

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed `MSSQLSERVER` in my laptop with default settings, and I have add some databases also. But if I start the `MSSQLSERVER` service then my laptop is prompting with low memory alert. My laptop configuration is `8GB i5 windows8.1`.

I check my task manager and I came to now that before staring the service the
the `committed memory` was `3.5/10.9 GB` but after staring it became `23.0/27GB` some times above `30GB`
Please help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors, including your server settings ("default" isn't too helpful), the database settings and size, etc. Check out this SE DBA question:

[Why is SQL Server consuming more server memory?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/why-is-sql-server-consuming-more-server-memory)

On this computer, I only have SQL Server 2005, but the general idea is the same:

[image: SQL Server 2005 Memory]

With these settings, it could theoretically take every bit of memory I have. But, mine currently only has a commit size of 106MB.

Also, your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It may be more appropriate for Server Fault or Database Administrators.